# C: stat does not show filesize properly for large files

Tags: c, ls, stat

I have a simple function to print file size and file name:

```
void *mystat(void *filename) {

    struct stat fileStat;

    if (lstat(filename,&fileStat) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no such file or directory: %s\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf(" %'d",fileStat.st_size);

    printf(" %s\n", filename);
}
```

it works fine for small files, but when file is large (couple of GB) it prints size `0`.

Why is this not working for large files ?

**EDIT**

Actually it only prints file size `0` when the file size is multiple of `4GB`. In other case, when file is large but not multiple, it prints negative number.

but, when I capture the return code of `lstat` and print it, it is `0`:

```
ret = lstat(filename,&fileStat)
```

I am compiling and running my code on a 64-bit system.

Obviously, the `fileStat.st_size` is overflowing, but why?

Comment: For that question, we probably need to know which system you're on. For example, if `off_t` is a 32-bit int type, it can only represent sizes of op to about 4 GB.

Comment: Check the `errno` value when `lstat` fails. It's likely to be `EOVERFLOW`. The [stat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) tells you why (and hence what to do to overcome it): "this error can occur when, for example, an application compiled on a 32-bit platform without -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 calls stat() on a file whose size exceeds (1<<31)-1 bytes."

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lstat` is giving you the right answer. It's `printf` that's the problem. Use `%'ld` instead of `%'d` to be good enough in practice, or if you want to be pedantically correct, then do this instead:

```
printf(" %'jd", (intmax_t)fileStat.st_size);
```

You may also need to `#include <stdint.h>`, if you get an error that `intmax_t` doesn't exist.

Comment: using `%'ld` works. Thank you. How would I use `%'jd` and cast to `intmax_t`? Could you please include the example in your answer ?

Comment: @400theCat I just added it.

Comment: I suspect 64-bit file lengths will be good until maybe 2070 or so.  By then `intmax_t` likely will exceed 64-bit.